# IBM Content Navigator. How to run search when feature opened

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

Can we configure a search to be automatically opened when selecting the search feature, I thought it was possible by configuration, but I can't find where I can configure it.
It already discussed on 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=fbac6330-f636-4745-924a-a713f4f9a309&ps=50&tags=&query=&filter=&sortBy=&order=asc
but there is no answer how to do it, only suggestion:  "You can code it with a plugin."
How this can be done using a plugin?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  From what you've written I have no idea what you need help with, and I shouldn't need to read another forum post to understand the question.  Also, what have you tried so far?  Have you run into a specific error?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found answer in internet. I was able to code it myself. Hopefully it will help somebody else.

I did monkey patching of ContentNavigator Dojo class ecm/widget/search/SearchSelector

Please see my code below:

```
            var searchSelectorPrototype = searchSelector.prototype; 
            var old_createTree = searchSelectorPrototype._createTree; 
            searchSelectorPrototype._createTree = function () {

                old_createTree.apply(this, arguments);

                this._tree.expandAll();// we need to expand tree to be able to get search templates by _tree.getNodesByItem("all")[0].getChildren();
                var that = this;

                var i = 0;
                var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,100);//need to wait until expandAll() completed
                function myTimer() {
                    i++;
                    var searchTemplates = that._tree.getNodesByItem("all")[0].getChildren();
                    if (i>50){
                        clearInterval(myVar);
                        console.log("not able to get search templates from _tree.getNodesByItem(\"all\")[0].getChildren()");
                    }
                    if (searchTemplates.length > 0 ){
                        clearInterval(myVar);
                        new searchPlugin.config.PluginConfig().getConfiguration(// we need to know which search template to open, I added configuration parameter "autoSearchTemplateName" to plugin
                            function(response) {
                                var templateName;
                                response.configuration.forEach(function (configurationItem) {
                                    if (configurationItem.name == 'autoSearchTemplateName'){
                                        templateName = configurationItem.value;
                                    }
                                });
                                array.forEach(searchTemplates, function(template){
                                    if(template.item.name === templateName){
                                        that.setSelected(template.item);
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }, that);
                            },
                            function(response) {
                                console.error(response);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
```